# How to get html report when the test-cases run in parallel?

Tags: karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am using karma-html-reporter to generate the report which works fine.
But when i execute the test-cases with karma-parallel i observe that it is generating the report of only one instance not for the other one.
Is there a way to get/generate report for both of the instances.
Currently i am running 2 instances of Chrome.
What all i have to do to get the integrated report of both instances ?

I have tried karma-multibrowser-reporter [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-multibrowser-reporter)
But it is removing the karma-parallel feature.

report generation happens with below configuration:-

```
htmlReporter: {
  outputDir: 'path/results'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

karma-parallel has the option `aggregatedReporterTest`. If you add html to the regex it only uses one reporter for all browsers:

```
parallelOptions: {
  aggregatedReporterTest: /coverage|istanbul|html|junit/i
},
```